# Scraping multiple links by scrapy

Tags: web, scrapy, screen-scraping

I scraped a web page & all the useful links I stored in a list & now I want to scrape those links which are in the list. So how may I do it?

Comment: welcome. it would be great to point out language or framework you are using in description as well. also please provide information such as what have you been tried so far.

Comment: i am using python for web scraping and python's scrapy package i am using for web scraping.

Answer (score 0):

This what i use for that:

```
for link in link_list:
   yield scrapy.Request(link, self.parse, method='GET')
```

Iterate through the list of links with a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

start your spider with: scrapy crawl spidername -O output.csv

after that you go like in your :

```py
    name = "spidername"
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    with open("output.csv","r") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=",")
        start_urls = [items['Link'] for items in reader]
```

'Link' is the header in your output.csv